# Change the loop computation to parallel computation

Tags: tensor

```
import torch
from tqdm import tqdm
# 定义图像a，b，c和d
a = torch.randint(0, 2, (8, 256, 256))
b = torch.randint(0, 15, (8, 256, 256))
c = torch.randint(0, 15, (8, 256, 256))
d = torch.randn(8, 2, 15, 15)

# 初始化图像e
def func(a,b,c,d):
    e = torch.zeros(8, 256, 256)
    # 遍历每个批次中的图像
    for batch_idx in tqdm(range(8)):
        # 遍历图像e的每个像素点
        for i in range(256):
            for j in range(256):
                # 获取a中的值确定通道
                channel_idx = int(a[batch_idx, i, j].item())

                # 获取b和c中的值确定在d中的位置
                row_idx = int(b[batch_idx, i, j].item())
                col_idx = int(c[batch_idx, i, j].item())

                # 获取d中的值并赋给e中对应位置
                e[batch_idx, i, j] = d[batch_idx, channel_idx, row_idx, col_idx]
    return e
```

This method of calculation is very slow,I want to replace it with parallel computing

I wanted to take advantage of the nature of tensor data to speed things up.